# DotNetOpenAuth consumer POSTing large data; "The Uri string is too long"

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

Related: [DotNetOpenAuth I Need Send Long string in FetchResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5449044/69683) and [OpenId query length issue in DotNetOpenAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4287313/69683) - but neither of these are able to answer my question satisfactorily.

We are using DotNetOpenAuth to post data to [Xero, which supports a maximum of 3MB per request](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/xero-api-limits/). We are trying to post a 77Kb XML string in `requestBody`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> additionalParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
additionalParams.Add("xml",requestBody);

var endpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(requestURL, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
HttpWebRequest request = XeroConsumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(endpoint, accessToken, additionalParams);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string thisResponse = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
```

`PrepareAuthorizedRequest` is throwing: `Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.`

Is there any way I can POST "large" data with DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: I don't get it. The error message isn't complaining about the POST data.

Comment: If I make `requestbody` something small, it works fine. When the `requestbpdy` is large, it gives the error. I am passing this through `PrepareAuthorizedRequest` - I have no idea what that particular function does - it's provided by DotNetOpenAuth and I haven't gone through its source yet. I assume it's using a URI builder and appending the XML data onto the end of the URL.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked different question - "I have a large file that I need to POST with OAuth. How?" only I didn't want it to look like I was asking someone else to do my work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth uses `Uri.HexEscape()` and `Uri.EscapeDataString()` on the additional parameters](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/v4.3/src/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/Messaging/MessagingUtilities.cs#L1947). This breaks when your parameters are over 2Kb in length.

I have swapped out their function for my own inefficient, but working, function:

```
    internal static string EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(string value)
    {
        StringBuilder escaped = new StringBuilder();

        string validChars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._~";

        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if(validChars.Contains(c.ToString())){
                escaped.Append(c);
            } else {
                escaped.Append("%" + Convert.ToByte(c).ToString("x2").ToUpper());
            }
        }

        // Return the fully-RFC3986-escaped string.
        return escaped.ToString();
    }
```